How can I set formatters for more than one column in React-Google-Charts?
Trying to use React Google Charts, I am facing a problem when I want to format several columns. In all the examples I found on the web, only one column is formatted through one of these two methods:
Method 1:
<Chart
            chartType="Table"
            width="700px"
            height="50%"
            data={data2}
            options={options}
            numberFormat={
                {
                    column: 6,
                    options: {
                        suffix: " €",
                        negativeColor: "red",
                        negativeParens: true,                
                    } 
                }
            }
        />`

Method 2:
 const formatters = [
        {
            type: "NumberFormat",
            column: 4,
            options: {
                pattern: "#",
            }
        }]
  <Chart
      chartType="Table"
      width="700px"
      height="50%"
      data={data2}
      options={options}
      formatters={formatters}
  />

Method 1 and Method 2 work fine but if I want to format columns 4 and 6, by extending the formatting array in any of the methods, only the first column will be formatted.
For example, I tried Method 2 with:
const formatters = [
        {
            type: "NumberFormat",
            column: 4,
            options: {
                pattern: "#Kg",
            }
        },
        {
            type: "NumberFormat",
            column: 6,
            options: {
                suffix: " €",
                negativeColor: "red",
                negativeParens: true,                
            } 
        }
    ]

and only column 4 was formatted.
If I permut the records then only column 6 will success.
Trying to play with brackets and/or parenthesis did not help.
